# Using del method with wildcard, excluding specific file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a .bat file to delete all files from a directory that look like "r" concatenated with a number of indeterminate length with a .sas7bdat ending.

e.g.: r2343.sas7bdat, r2309483.sas7bdat, etc.

The problem is, that I also have a file called "ranker_interface.sas7bdat", so I can't just do:

del "C:\temp\r*.sas7bdat"

I've tried Googling this up and down, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Is there any way of excluding a particular value from a wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /L %%a in (0,1,9) do ECHO del r%%a*.sas7bdat
```

would possibly be easiest.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

If you are running this directly from the prompt rather than as a line in a batch file, change all `%%a`  to `%a`.

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm going to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is the old school MSDOS way of getting around this:

```
attrib +h "C:\temp\ranker*.sas7bdat"
del "C:\temp\r*.sas7bdat"
attrib -h "C:\temp\ranker*.sas7bdat"
```

The attrib command hides the files you don't want deleted from the DEL command,
and then unhides them again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it worked, but I'm going to use the answer above from Magoo.

Answer (score 0):

To list down all files from folder that are like 'r*.sas7bdat', exclude the one from the list called ranker_interface.sas7bdat and delete the rest you can use this command from within batch file:

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b r*.sas7bdat ^| find /v "ranker_interface.sas7bdat"') do del /f /q %%a
```

It is written the way to be executed from the folder directly.
This will delete all 'r*.sas7bdat' but the one specified by `find /v` - exclusion, that can eventually be followed by another `find /v` exclusion, so something like:

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b r*.sas7bdat ^| find /v "ranker_interface.sas7bdat" ^| find /v "rxxxxx.sas7bdat"') do del /f /q %%a
```

Not the best way if you want to exclude more than one file. If you want to exclude more than  one file, then you can put your excluded filenames into singel file and isntead of directly running `del` command further `for` followed by `if` statements can be done and compare the file if can be found in exclusion list file, that contain file name on each row. Batch can look like this then:

```
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b r*.sas7bdat') do (
       for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('type exclusion.txt ^| find /c "%%a"') do (
          if "%%x" EQU "0" (del /f /q %%a)
       )
    )
```

This will delete all files in your directory that are like 'r*.sas7bdat', except those listed down in file 'exclusion.txt'

Hope this helps